# Is it true that Canonical shares some user's information with Amazon without asking for permission to Ubuntu's user?

Tags: canonical, amazon

I heard Richard Stallman saying it... 
He says Ubuntu violates the privacy of the user by giving information to Amazon without permission.

Comment: From here: http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2257118/richard-stallman-says-ubuntu-linux-is-spyware , I see: "Although Ubuntu users can opt out and Canonical claims it anonymises users' search information before sending it to Amazon". So from this, yes, it does this by default, but it's _apparently_ opt-out-able.

Comment: This does not belong in AskUbuntu. It should be posted in meta.

Comment: Oh, it's very valid to me...